# How to scrape specific information from javascript webpage by Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I can't scrape the 'Resolution' field from the javascript webpage, as I believe.
Webpage address:
https://support.na.sage.com/selfservice/viewdocument.do?noCount=true&externalId=60390&sliceId=1&noCount=true&isLoadPublishedVer=&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_Article&stateId=4183&cmd=displayKC&dialogID=197243&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl&openedFromSearchResults=true
I need to extract Description, Cause, and Resolution.

Tried various ways to get element, including:

- find_element_by_xpath
- find_element_by_id
- find_element_by_class_name.

Nothing gave the desired result.
Could you direct me in which way should I work?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you show us your code and what you've tried so far? In addition, it helps to include the error traceback.

Comment: elements = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, ".//*")))
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)

Comment: results_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@id='extiframe']/li[@class='extiframe']")
print(len(results_list))

results_list = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#extiframe > li')
print(len(results_list))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.na.sage.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=60390&sliceId=1
This is the correct url that you can crawl html, use Network tab of your browser devtool to find that.
Example with Chrome
[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! That looks promising. Unfortunately, this website has stopped me to scrape the info. The search button is inactive. Probably, there is a rule to charge a requester after a certain number of questions, I guess.